# Bootnodes for Rococo

Tags: parachain, rococo, parachain-collator

After completing the cumulus tutorial, I'm trying to connect the parachain to Rococo. I have two questions

1. Do we need to run our own validator nodes for Rococo? (my understanding is that its not needed)
2. If step 1 is not needed, how do we connect to the Rococo relaychain nodes, I have previously used `-- -- chain rococo` at the end of the start command to connect the parachain to rococo, but that is no longer working.

The startup command used

```
./target/release/parachain \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 9944 \
--rpc-port 9979 --rpc-cors all --discover-local \
--rpc-external --rpc-methods=unsafe \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain rococo
```

The parachain logs

```
2022-04-20 09:27:56 [Parachain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xf223…16d5, header-hash: 0x0626…9b5d)    
2022-04-20 09:27:58 [Relaychain]  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0x43ea…c82a, header-hash: 0xaaf2…7897)    
2022-04-20 09:27:58 [Relaychain]  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain]  Creating empty BABE epoch changes on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWLy23nK6ke5guymJCnrv9DuenT3wGfwfFARo4TBj6tEQA    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain]  Highest known block at #0    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9616    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain] Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9945.    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Parachain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWBRhKyabqGxhzm7LSrbgNepLPYLY8C9cMHYQQFPZg99Bn    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Parachain]  Highest known block at #0    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Parachain] 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Parachain] Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:9944.    
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain] error=RollingSessionWindow(SessionsUnavailable { kind: RuntimeApi(Execution { runtime_api_name: "SessionInfo", source: FailedToDecodeReturnValue { function: "session_info", error: Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: Some(Error { cause: None, desc: "Not enough data to fill buffer" }), desc: "Could not decode `Public.0`" }), desc: "Could not decode `Public.0`" }), desc: "Could not decode `SessionInfo::validators`" }), desc: "Could not decode `Option::Some(T)`" } } }), info: Some(SessionsUnavailableInfo { window_start: 0, window_end: 0, block_hash: 0xaaf2cd1b74b5f726895921259421b534124726263982522174147046b8827897 }) })
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain] Received msg before first active leaves update. This is not expected - message will be dropped. msg=ActiveDisputes(Sender { complete: false })
2022-04-20 09:27:59 [Relaychain] error=Sender(AskActiveDisputesCanceled) ctx="on FromOverseer"
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWD6wC88atMMyVeP6ZKg9sK7QmUL8x8m1RxMW8rhv2vWyg` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)    
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWF7BUbG5ErMZ47ZdarRwtpZamgcZqxwpnFzkhjc1spHnP` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)    
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWLcpkpvjr5ccgtUdTSYtNDjEdsDcPNrt2Rb7yXuAf7bUE` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)    
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWSV4VqhBHZKKBsZKmVU462qRW9PmXTSuYvuajt1P93djA` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)    
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWBhkZQydNHDR3XSehnrfj1KNFCdpwgDrYpX54FrUR1FRS` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)    
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWBuLAMevZexnFKCgTyoz3AnHQn98D9cfe1Mg3kPoCjkwf` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)    
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWA5BAM71y9NtV5NH6EjANgYKRZ8jNLJ5z8GJ5RPdjt63n` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)    
2022-04-20 09:28:00 [Relaychain] Bootnode with peer id `12D3KooWGjEEDmNbBkXLM1uKMseK9iYD3osKA4JGdGKMZDCusjd6` is on a different chain (our genesis: 0xaaf2…7897 theirs: 0x27b0…c184)        
2022-04-20 09:28:03 [Relaychain] Received msg before first active leaves update. This is not expected - message will be dropped. msg=ActiveDisputes(Sender { complete: false })
```

using polkadot-0.9.18 and tested locally with polkadot release-v00.9.18 branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be using the wrong chain spec of Rococo.

The one running was included in this PR: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/5113/commits/e9a0947de83f8ced4402a6d2df54dd78d861369d

Comment: You were right, using the chainspec you shared solved the issue. Although I have another question, when I started the node I can see this
```  
2022-04-20 13:20:09 [Relaychain] Block import error: Database    
2022-04-20 13:20:09 [Relaychain] ? Error importing block 0xef24675155e6e5fe947e: consensus error: Import failed: Import failed: Database    
2022-04-20 13:20:09 [Relaychain] DB corrupted: Corruption: Corrupted compressed block contents: Snappy. Repair will be triggered on next restart    
``` but fixes itself and starts syncing in ~30sec. Is this normal?

Comment: Asked as seperate question here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/database-corruption-on-syncing-parachain-to-rococo