# Database corruption on syncing parachain to rococo

Tags: parachain, rococo, parachain-collator

Syncing parachain to rococo generates the following error:

```
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain] DB corrupted: Corruption: Corrupted compressed block contents: Snappy. Repair will be triggered on next restart    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain] Block import error: Database    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0xf70389c0893eb2603c86c087d5472bcdf63e401f9cd9d46e8ac4678009c652fb: consensus error: Import failed: Import failed: Database    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0x2474ce5dbf0075dd96a6af41b3d7e846473ce571ecae9b74d268d198294b8801: block has an unknown parent    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0xaf3e7e3e4429cf3dae316fa074d688d660c45eed5d18ad2cfa6a72ac87f4830f: block has an unknown parent    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0xcddc29180173f0024f5de514b5c5476260840dde0a09241b0ed031c54e2efb2e: block has an unknown parent    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0xe77146a356ccc0b422cc192d4eb9b6d956d5e6bed5f7ba6a2ebca873b659d7b3: block has an unknown parent    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0xdf3d7de4ab483214165a37667b1be4a405991fa669f7fbb3ac75b200fbc8e5b0: block has an unknown parent    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0x97e17ed1120a0e0e2835936cc9eb89457f15d7054d86f895ab1e655129975350: block has an unknown parent    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain] DB corrupted: Corruption: Corrupted compressed block contents: Snappy. Repair will be triggered on next restart    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain] Block import error: Database    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0xf70389c0893eb2603c86c087d5472bcdf63e401f9cd9d46e8ac4678009c652fb: consensus error: Import failed: Import failed: Database    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain]  Error importing block 0x3784e3a954b95f9c478720a7a0bb6d1f343301b673c5bb67cef351482f98790f: block has an unknown parent    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain] DB corrupted: Corruption: Corrupted compressed block contents: Snappy. Repair will be triggered on next restart    
2022-04-20 16:47:13 [Relaychain] Block import error: Database
```

Startup command used

```
./target/release/parachain \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 9944 \
--rpc-port 9979 --rpc-cors all --discover-local \
--rpc-external --rpc-methods=unsafe \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain rococo.json
```

Using the latest rococo.json from https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/res/rococo.json

The error goes away after some time but syncing does not happen (0 bps)

```
2022-04-20 16:49:45 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0626…9b5d), finalized #0 (0x0626…9b5d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-20 16:49:45 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#531880 (1 peers), best: #722 (0x6452…e6ea), finalized #512 (0xd1b3…6a0a), ⬇ 10.0kiB/s ⬆ 10.1kiB/s    
2022-04-20 16:49:50 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0626…9b5d), finalized #0 (0x0626…9b5d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-20 16:49:50 [Relaychain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #722 (0x6452…e6ea), finalized #512 (0xd1b3…6a0a), ⬇ 7.2kiB/s ⬆ 7.5kiB/s    
2022-04-20 16:49:55 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0626…9b5d), finalized #0 (0x0626…9b5d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-20 16:49:55 [Relaychain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #722 (0x6452…e6ea), finalized #512 (0xd1b3…6a0a), ⬇ 9.0kiB/s ⬆ 9.0kiB/s    
2022-04-20 16:50:00 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0626…9b5d), finalized #0 (0x0626…9b5d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-20 16:50:00 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#531883 (1 peers), best: #722 (0x6452…e6ea), finalized #512 (0xd1b3…6a0a), ⬇ 9.7kiB/s ⬆ 10.3kiB/s    
2022-04-20 16:50:05 [Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0626…9b5d), finalized #0 (0x0626…9b5d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-04-20 16:50:05 [Relaychain] ⚙️  Syncing  0.0 bps, target=#531883 (1 peers), best: #722 (0x6452…e6ea), finalized #512 (0xd1b3…6a0a), ⬇ 8.2kiB/s ⬆ 8.4kiB/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Found similar behaviour on one of our networks. After spitting out errors like

```
2022-09-22 12:17:10  Verification failed for block 0xa06d1231c7ad3403216a427883e18bccc95e461c902ff430f13543ce7c11f5d3 received from peer: 12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm, "Bad signature on 0xa06d1231c7ad3403216a427883e18bccc95e461c902ff430f13543ce7c11f5d3"    
2022-09-22 12:17:10  Error importing block 0x4ff8f2d4afa5fe8ba85c01fff2da3879530ed04fb48f6734ede824a3da4f4be3: block has an unknown parent    
2022-09-22 12:17:10  Error importing block 0x31032caf935bda7e701a77f642c9c409c901d54962ce80b7cd2e7f4ce658fa03: block has an unknown parent    
2022-09-22 12:17:10  Error importing block 0xb3c7bc381923bebd2b60bb7044994df9b3ce3ea47e03080d43cfc1fa73a3f7e9: block has an unknown parent    
2022-09-22 12:17:10  Error importing block 0x19a7a12c81cb6e9ad6252f98e8b5cb5077b780d8e0407a9cbee09eb7ca18e36f: block has an unknown parent    
2022-09-22 12:17:10  Error importing block 0xe7dfc86ae36d0df2aae2803f3d382afde92fbdd9b3f33d3d137982a9075b8167: block has an unknown parent
```

It loses all its peer and cannot sync anymore:

```
2022-09-22 12:17:25  Idle (0 peers), best: #113254 (0x9511…8c92), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 1.5kiB/s ⬆ 1.5kiB/s    
2022-09-22 12:17:30  Idle (0 peers), best: #113254 (0x9511…8c92), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 4.6kiB/s ⬆ 5.7kiB/s    
2022-09-22 12:17:35  Idle (0 peers), best: #113254 (0x9511…8c92), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 2.3kiB/s ⬆ 3.2kiB/s    
2022-09-22 12:17:40  Idle (0 peers), best: #113254 (0x9511…8c92), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 20.5kiB/s ⬆ 12.5kiB/s    
2022-09-22 12:17:45  Idle (0 peers), best: #113254 (0x9511…8c92), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 1.1kiB/s ⬆ 1.9kiB/s    
2022-09-22 12:17:50  Idle (0 peers), best: #113254 (0x9511…8c92), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 3.3kiB/s ⬆ 3.5kiB/s    
2022-09-22 12:17:55  Idle (0 peers), best: #113254 (0x9511…8c92), finalized #113152 (0x5062…70ed), ⬇ 1.7kiB/s ⬆ 1.9kiB/s
```

Something to note: We recently upgraded our network from substrate V3 to substrate (polkadot-0.9.24). If we try to sync a node with a release that is still on substrate V3 we don't receive this error. But then it stops syncing at the block where we upgraded to polkadot-0.9.24.

To me, this is kind of weird. The code should be backward compatible, I should be able to sync the entire chain even with the code being on polkadot-0.9.24

After running the same coomand with `-l sync trace` I see following output:

```
2022-09-22 14:42:41.220  INFO                 main sc_rpc_server: Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944, allowed origins=Some(["http://localhost:*", "http://127.0.0.1:*", "https://localhost:*", "https://127.0.0.1:*", "https://polkadot.js.org"])    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.221  INFO tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_mdns::behaviour::iface: creating instance on iface 192.168.8.106    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.221  INFO tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_mdns::behaviour::iface: creating instance on iface 192.168.8.98    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.221  INFO tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_mdns::behaviour::iface: creating instance on iface 192.168.49.1    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.221  INFO tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_mdns::behaviour::iface: creating instance on iface 172.17.0.1    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.221  INFO tokio-runtime-worker libp2p_mdns::behaviour::iface: creating instance on iface 192.168.8.117    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.233 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWMPnWPkAi9UhVgGv9QmozXiPDE94rymPCsXLJ5EKynwta BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: AUTHORITY, best_number: 2433159, best_hash: 0xe6ba5b10461adb68dc1d094127d92556437a95df0d5f3be1e8fd648f59d7d333, genesis_hash: 0xbb7f298ba5fca8802040061ddd0ca6406832238b7825ebfa66927cc25ec666be }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.233 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer with unknown best hash 0xe6ba…d333 (2433159), searching for common ancestor.    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.233 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Connected 12D3KooWMPnWPkAi9UhVgGv9QmozXiPDE94rymPCsXLJ5EKynwta    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.234 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: AUTHORITY, best_number: 2433159, best_hash: 0xe6ba5b10461adb68dc1d094127d92556437a95df0d5f3be1e8fd648f59d7d333, genesis_hash: 0xbb7f298ba5fca8802040061ddd0ca6406832238b7825ebfa66927cc25ec666be }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.234 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer with unknown best hash 0xe6ba…d333 (2433159), searching for common ancestor.    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.234 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Connected 12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.264 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWAnibsVN4yBcKNKnnRm8pxmHkEf3DUT65dpb3P252RpZK BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: AUTHORITY, best_number: 2433159, best_hash: 0xe6ba5b10461adb68dc1d094127d92556437a95df0d5f3be1e8fd648f59d7d333, genesis_hash: 0xbb7f298ba5fca8802040061ddd0ca6406832238b7825ebfa66927cc25ec666be }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.264 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer with unknown best hash 0xe6ba…d333 (2433159), searching for common ancestor.    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.264 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Connected 12D3KooWAnibsVN4yBcKNKnnRm8pxmHkEf3DUT65dpb3P252RpZK    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.264 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: BlockResponse 0 from 12D3KooWMPnWPkAi9UhVgGv9QmozXiPDE94rymPCsXLJ5EKynwta with 1 blocks  (113254)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.265 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Got ancestry block #113254 (0x9511…8c92) from peer 12D3KooWMPnWPkAi9UhVgGv9QmozXiPDE94rymPCsXLJ5EKynwta    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.265 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Ancestry search complete. Ours=0x9511…8c92 (113254), Theirs=0xe6ba…d333 (2433159), Common=Some(0x95119158e50bd9ed70e9b986560737aa09ff1e935a4102781464e4c499ca8c92) (113254)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.265 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New block request for 12D3KooWMPnWPkAi9UhVgGv9QmozXiPDE94rymPCsXLJ5EKynwta, (best:2433159, common:113254) BlockRequest { id: 0, fields: HEADER | BODY | JUSTIFICATION, from: Number(113318), to: None, direction: Descending, max: Some(64) }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.265 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: BlockResponse 0 from 12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm with 1 blocks  (113254)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.265 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Got ancestry block #113254 (0x9511…8c92) from peer 12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.265 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Ancestry search complete. Ours=0x9511…8c92 (113254), Theirs=0xe6ba…d333 (2433159), Common=Some(0x95119158e50bd9ed70e9b986560737aa09ff1e935a4102781464e4c499ca8c92) (113254)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.265 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New block request for 12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm, (best:2433159, common:113254) BlockRequest { id: 0, fields: HEADER | BODY | JUSTIFICATION, from: Number(113382), to: None, direction: Descending, max: Some(64) }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.269 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Request to peer PeerId("12D3KooWMPnWPkAi9UhVgGv9QmozXiPDE94rymPCsXLJ5EKynwta") failed: Refused.    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.269 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWMPnWPkAi9UhVgGv9QmozXiPDE94rymPCsXLJ5EKynwta disconnected    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.269 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: 0 blocks ready for import    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.269 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Request to peer PeerId("12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm") failed: Refused.    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.269 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWBkwH8LfJsz48Q8LHXSQnuqKJK8YdoQokDeS9wQX1j8mm disconnected    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.269 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: 0 blocks ready for import    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.271 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: BlockResponse 0 from 12D3KooWAnibsVN4yBcKNKnnRm8pxmHkEf3DUT65dpb3P252RpZK with 1 blocks  (113254)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.271 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Got ancestry block #113254 (0x9511…8c92) from peer 12D3KooWAnibsVN4yBcKNKnnRm8pxmHkEf3DUT65dpb3P252RpZK    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.271 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Ancestry search complete. Ours=0x9511…8c92 (113254), Theirs=0xe6ba…d333 (2433159), Common=Some(0x95119158e50bd9ed70e9b986560737aa09ff1e935a4102781464e4c499ca8c92) (113254)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.271 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New block request for 12D3KooWAnibsVN4yBcKNKnnRm8pxmHkEf3DUT65dpb3P252RpZK, (best:2433159, common:113254) BlockRequest { id: 0, fields: HEADER | BODY | JUSTIFICATION, from: Number(113318), to: None, direction: Descending, max: Some(64) }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.276 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Request to peer PeerId("12D3KooWAnibsVN4yBcKNKnnRm8pxmHkEf3DUT65dpb3P252RpZK") failed: Refused.    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.276 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWAnibsVN4yBcKNKnnRm8pxmHkEf3DUT65dpb3P252RpZK disconnected    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.276 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: 0 blocks ready for import    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.372 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWPWC1mBZwpWBNHRNeqo4MgoRmAos5wBSCZeD2KezEt3LE BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: FULL, best_number: 3841554, best_hash: 0xf7977dc2ef88656ef44389fa14c4296d9c93eb0bd3b5d5a49b1fdc17a51b7da1, genesis_hash: 0x225a01072ee42d335861e6a76ed457556d3e7ded16c577cc669ed15550815579 }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.372 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Peer is on different chain (our genesis: 0xbb7f…66be theirs: 0x225a…5579)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.372 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWPWC1mBZwpWBNHRNeqo4MgoRmAos5wBSCZeD2KezEt3LE disconnected    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.372 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Disconnected peer which had earlier been refused by on_sync_peer_connected 12D3KooWPWC1mBZwpWBNHRNeqo4MgoRmAos5wBSCZeD2KezEt3LE    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.382 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWP77QXcz6DcSn98udtbrirgfefjLRE9w5t5sYUxZTz8WX BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: AUTHORITY, best_number: 1620862, best_hash: 0xf2428b3e76685ec67a77a01f9220709eed1c7d478eceb691ac2a91f01efe11df, genesis_hash: 0xffe36f258bba7f5ea972b6a74c094c96bf50fd36438143e28ed6a48783986562 }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.382 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Peer is on different chain (our genesis: 0xbb7f…66be theirs: 0xffe3…6562)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.382 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWP77QXcz6DcSn98udtbrirgfefjLRE9w5t5sYUxZTz8WX disconnected    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.382 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Disconnected peer which had earlier been refused by on_sync_peer_connected 12D3KooWP77QXcz6DcSn98udtbrirgfefjLRE9w5t5sYUxZTz8WX    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.384 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWB9zsBmpvGhQ7BSBN4GHLbqt3pmgmgiGvHJ1LcWaYJvFF BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: AUTHORITY, best_number: 4869697, best_hash: 0xf038ba7f9d6ff94aaf91fdeff622052dd455e55f6de453dae288efd3e33d1974, genesis_hash: 0x0378abe88c21bd382106e7977902eef4f542bb2d3e67e8a318151e323b2d0660 }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.384 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Peer is on different chain (our genesis: 0xbb7f…66be theirs: 0x0378…0660)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.384 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWB9zsBmpvGhQ7BSBN4GHLbqt3pmgmgiGvHJ1LcWaYJvFF disconnected    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.384 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Disconnected peer which had earlier been refused by on_sync_peer_connected 12D3KooWB9zsBmpvGhQ7BSBN4GHLbqt3pmgmgiGvHJ1LcWaYJvFF    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.386 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWRaCqbuBvTWs2SgVTfYwqVdTunvGAbFo7dS4sBnXFaykK BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: FULL, best_number: 1620862, best_hash: 0xf2428b3e76685ec67a77a01f9220709eed1c7d478eceb691ac2a91f01efe11df, genesis_hash: 0xffe36f258bba7f5ea972b6a74c094c96bf50fd36438143e28ed6a48783986562 }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.386 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Peer is on different chain (our genesis: 0xbb7f…66be theirs: 0xffe3…6562)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.386 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWRaCqbuBvTWs2SgVTfYwqVdTunvGAbFo7dS4sBnXFaykK disconnected    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.386 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: Disconnected peer which had earlier been refused by on_sync_peer_connected 12D3KooWRaCqbuBvTWs2SgVTfYwqVdTunvGAbFo7dS4sBnXFaykK    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.388 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker sync: New peer 12D3KooWJ2np78u3hSQrLXbJp1EsRyiwzs7S6DXxq1vdFeS5cPQa BlockAnnouncesHandshake { roles: FULL, best_number: 3841554, best_hash: 0xf7977dc2ef88656ef44389fa14c4296d9c93eb0bd3b5d5a49b1fdc17a51b7da1, genesis_hash: 0x225a01072ee42d335861e6a76ed457556d3e7ded16c577cc669ed15550815579 }    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.388 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: Peer is on different chain (our genesis: 0xbb7f…66be theirs: 0x225a…5579)    
2022-09-22 14:42:41.388 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker sync: 12D3KooWJ2np78u3hSQrLXbJp1EsRyiwzs7S6DXxq1vdFeS5cPQa disconnected
```

It gets "refused" from my bootstrap peerlist, disconnects them and then receives connection requests from different kind of unknown peers..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the fix? I got same issue and reported here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/problem-in-syncing-with-rococo-getting-database-block-import-error

Comment: Hi, I found a way to fix it here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10103